# Add product to cart on customer registration in magento

Tags: magento

I want that when customer register product (which is choosen in backend) should get added to cart. I have done this :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                            ->load(154);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, 1)->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

in AccountController.php in createPostAction().

But it is not showing but whenever customer buys anything it gets added into cart. I am doing anything wrong...?

-Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the quote object in the session has already collected totals and would not do it again when the cart is saved. Because of this the quote's item count is zero, even though a quote item has been successfully added and saved. Modify your code like this:

```
$cart->product($product, 1);
$cart->getQuote()->setData('totals_collected_flag', false);
$cart->save();
```

And this should solve the problem.

A suggestion: would it not be better to implement this functionality in an observer listening to the `customer_register_success` event?